# Change lightness to pixels which are outside of the area

Tags: c++, opencv

I have one point set to position (x,y) and two angles from this point. I draw in example bellow two lines for demonstration, how it should look.

Now what I want is change lightness to all pixels outside from this lines.

Here is original image.

[image: original image]

And here is example, what I want.

[image: Wanted image]

How can I easy change pixels with Opencv(C++), if I have and know input image, point, and two angles? I know many of solution, but I want easiest one, how can detect which pixels need change and which not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to:

1. Make a binary mask of the size of the original image, based on your points and angle (i.e draw filled polygon).
2. Make a clone of the original image. Apply brightness changes to the whole of cloned image.
3. Copy cloned image back to original image based on the mask.

Comment: Or even do the operations in-place, if what you need supports masking. This answer would be better if it also included some code to demonstrate the approach.

Comment: @DanMašek I intentionally avoided adding any code because the OP seems to be asking for a general method and didn't add a code snippet of his own. Since not all OpenCV functions support masked operations, I tried to give a general solution that does not depend on in-place operations.

Comment: I understand. From experience, the elaborate answers tend to be good long-term rep earners ;) And usually a useful excercise anyway. Just a friendly hint, there's your upvote since this is still useful.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks :D

Comment: @DanMašek I include code from this suggestion of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I write code bellow from @Zindarod [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228405/2050745). Hope to help someone.
Angles are in degress.

```
void view(cv::Mat& frame, double angle_left, double angle_right, cv::Point center){
    int length = 1500;
    cv::Point left_view;
    left_view.x = (int)round(center.x + length * cos((angle_left * (CV_PI / 180))));
    left_view.y = (int)round(center.y + length * sin((angle_left * (CV_PI / 180))));

    cv::Point right_view;
    right_view.x = (int)round(center.x + length * cos((angle_right * (CV_PI / 180))));
    right_view.y = (int)round(center.y + length * sin((angle_right * (CV_PI / 180))));

    cv::Point pts[4] = { position_of_eyes, left_view, right_view, position_of_eyes };
    Mat mask = Mat(frame.size(), CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 0.3));
    cv::fillConvexPoly(mask, pts, 3, cv::Scalar(1.0,1.0,1.0));
    cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2HSV);
    frame.convertTo(frame, CV_32FC3);
    cv::multiply(frame, mask, frame);
    frame.convertTo(frame, CV_8UC3);
    cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_HSV2BGR);
}
```

Comment: I am nitpicking here but for optimization purposes try to use OpenCV's built in functions as much as you can and try to avoid user defined nested loops. You can replace your loops with `split(hsv, channels); channels.at(2) *= 0.3;     merge(channels, hsv);`.

Comment: @Zindarod I did not know that before. What about the time complexity? `split` and `merge` take more time?

Comment: They take less time, that's why I recommended it. For a 4K image your nested loops take an of 50ms, while the `split` and `merge` take an average 30ms,

Comment: @Zindarod I Update answer to more optimal.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Given an origin point and two angles, you can calculate 2 unit vectors for you two lines, let these be unitA and unitB.

For each pixel of the image do these steps: 
 
1. get a vector (called vec) from the origin to the pixel. 
 
2. find the angle (ang) between vec and a reference vector (refVec). 
 
3. if ang is greater than the angle between refVec and unitA, but smaller than the angle between the refVec and unitB recolor the pixel.